# Going to a stadium, to watch a game, during Sefirah

Tags: halacha, sefirat-ha-omer, sport-athletics, performance-entertainment

R' Moshe Feinstein [forbids](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/71217/do-any-gedolim-forbid-attending-a-sporting-event) going to stadiums to watch sporting events all year round.

But some rabbis rule differently than R' Feinstein. See, for example, [this link](http://dinonline.org/2016/05/10/attending-sporting-events/), as well as the ruling of R' Sheinberg quoted near the bottom of [this link](http://www.dafyomi.co.il/azarah/insites/az-dt-018.htm).

According to those rabbis who permit attending sporting events during the rest of the year, would you also be allowed to go to a sporting event (e.g. soccer, basketball, baseball) during Sefirat Ha'omer?

I know that you are not allowed to listen to live music or go to plays or things of that sort, but I am unsure if going to watch a professional game would be allowed or not (for example, MLB, NBA, NFL, or NHL).

Comment: Have to find a supporting source. FWIW, I think the prohibition is primarily against listening to music. I was younger ... once. Many of my yeshiva friends and I attended ball games during Sefira, and, I see many religious in my neighborhood doing this, now. Admittedly, it's tough to tell if they are doing it before or after their personal "Sefirah zone", as there are 2 main customs.

Comment: I would like you to rephrase the question so that it does not sound like you are asking for a Pesak.

Comment: it isprohibited every day as I already commented, because of moshav letsim

Answer (score 3):

In a Shi'ur I attended many years ago, Rav Binyamin Tabory of Yeshivat Har Etzion once expressed his opinion that the custom is to refrain from activities that are public experiences that enhance joy.  To the extent that this is true, he felt that going to movies (which is something many people avoid during Sefirah) is perfectly acceptable from the Sefirah angle (or would be, if not for the fact that he felt there is no such thing as a "Kosher" movie; he told a story of a supposedly "Kosher" movie he attended in the 1960s that had "inappropriate" previews), because you do not experience joy, but in fact experience frustration, if others in the theater try to share the experience with you.  In contrast to that, he stated that the atmosphere at a baseball stadium (to use his example) was one that perfectly exemplified the type of public experience that enhances joy, and should be avoided during Sefirah.

Answer (score -1):

The question of whether or not you can watch a game during Sefira is a moot question. I believe you can never watch a professional-sports match, whether it's Sefira or not.

---

Hashem warns us, “… do not perform the practices of the land of Canaan to which I bring you and do not follow their customs" (Vayikra 18:3).

On the words, “do not follow their customs,” Rashi says, “… Matters that are etched 
for them in their ways as if they were laws, such as theaters and stadiums i.e., (days set aside for) attendance at theaters or stadiums…”

The Gemara (Sotah 5a) says, “Whenever it is stated in the Torah ‘do not,’ it is nothing other than a negative commandment.” Rashi is telling us, “Do not go to a Movie Theater (i.e. IMAX) or a Sport Stadium.”

Excerpted from [*A Solution for Jew Hatred*](https://www.dropbox.com/s/57p3z3u48d1dmia/A%20Solution%20for%20Jew%20Hatred.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: Visiting a stadium might still be forbidden nowadays, but the severity of the prohibition might now be less. See [here](http://dinonline.org/2016/05/13/theatres-and-stadiums/).

Comment: People attend games the whole year. He just wants to know if your allowed to attend during sefirah...

Comment: The question was clearly "According to those rabbis who permit attending sporting events during the rest of the year". I don't see how this answers the question.