# Do any Gedolim forbid attending a sporting event?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, men-male, sport-athletics

Does a male violate any halacha in the Torah by watching a ball game at a sports stadium?

Are there any Gedolim that oppose going?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Mi Yodeya. I hope you find the sources you are looking for.

Comment: related tangentially http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/21912/is-it-asur-to-watch-violent-sports

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/69508/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13824/759

Comment: Q - Is the focus of this question only on the aspect of watching a team play a sports game where, say, a man watches male baseball players? Or are you including in "sports" a man going to the Olympics to watch the women in the swimming competition, where they may be an issue of tzniut, etc.?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39711/discussion-on-question-by-real-torah-do-any-gedolim-forbid-attending-a-sporting).

Comment: Real Torah, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for the interesting question! If you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). 
I hope you find more Q&A of interest and stay learning with us!

Answer (score 8):

Rav Moshe Feinstein in his Igros Moshe Chelek 8:4 YD :11 writes that going to theaters and stadiums do not fall into the prohibition of bechukoseihem lo tolechu. However, he writes that one is prohibited from attending due to moshev letzim, bitul Torah (eventually l'gamri), nivul peh (promiscuity). Rav Moshe is clear that it is a forbidden to attend such places.

http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14679&st=&pgnum=212

Comment: see related sources at http://machzikeihadas.blogspot.com/2009/02/moshav-leitzim.html

Comment: Why is there a problem of nibul (the way it should be pronounced) peh in *watching* a sporting event or movie? There is an issur in hearing it?

Comment: as it is forbidden to talk Nivul Peh so too it is forbidden to hear it from someone else. (See Sha’arei Teshuva Sha’ar 3 Siman 229. See also Talmud Kesubos 5b that Hashem created the earlobe soft and flexible so that it can be inserted in the ear to block out any forbidden speech one may hear, including Nivul Peh.)
Just as by Devarim SheBikedusah there is a concept of Shomea K’Oneh, where one who hears a holy utterance is as if he himself said it, so too with Nivul Peh, one who hears it & able to avoid] is considered as if he himself is speaking it. (Shla Hakadosh, Sha’ar HaOsiyos, Kedusha)