# Mixed-gender seating for entertainment

Tags: halacha, tznius-modesty, performance-entertainment, secular-culture, mechitza-partition

There is a heter some poskim and rabbis  (i.e. Rabbi Moshe Feinstein) give to sit on public transportation next to someone of the opposite gender. My question is, what is the halacha in regards to sitting next to someone of the opposite gender during a large secular event, such as a sports game, concert, or movie? Would one be required to sit across a mechitza?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12256/the-laws-behind-the-separation-of-men-and-women?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Depending on the event, you might have bigger issues.

Comment: @N.T.  I think that's an answer.

Comment: Another related possible duplicate. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/69508/7303